# Subversion - How to disable the requirement of commit message in svn?

Tags: svn

How to disable the requirement of commit message in svn?

I don't mean `pre-commit` hook with `insert 1 space to empty message`. I mean disable this requirement in server configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no server-side default requirement for commit messages at all. The only way to control this is either a server-side pre-commit hook or client-side settings.

[SVNBook | Repository Maintenance](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks.uses):

> On the validation side of things, the start-commit and pre-commit
>   hooks are widely used to allow or disallow commits based on various
>   criteria: the author of the commit, the formatting and/or content of
>   the log message which describes the commit, and even the low-level
>   details of the changes made to files and directories in the commit.

Comment: @Y.N what link exactly?

Comment: May be here http://subversion.apache.org/docs/ - some explanation about commit message hard requirement